# Phrase describing increased secondary level demand

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase (or related) that describes the following phenomenon:
Product A sees an increased demand from buyer group X, therefore prices for A increase. This will also affect the purchasing behaviour of buyer group Y, the ones who would buy A under normal circumstances.
Due to the increased price, many out of Y are now buying product B instead, which serves as an alternative for them but is of no interest for X. Now the increased demand for B causes its price to raise as well.

Comment: Cascade effect.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely related, though quite generic. I was hoping for some phrase that implies the context of market dynamics.

Comment: Maybe you'll find appropriate ideas on appropriate Q&A rather than on a language Q&A.

Comment: ? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110851/sales-and-marketing

Comment: Similar to @Kris suggestion: **Domino effect** or **Ripple effect**. You could also try asking here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might be helpful (although only comments, no answers): https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/17350

Comment: @SteveES I think cross elasticity is pretty close to what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Substitution is the process whereby one product is chosen over another due to an increase in price, reduction in supply.  The other phrase that maybe of use is the notion of switching cost, the cost the consumer bears (not always financial, perhaps a reduce quality or shorter warranty) in order to switch from product A to product B.  You could also use the phrase price contagion to explain that a shift in behaviour was sourced outside of the main buyer group.

Comment: For context, see [Porter](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/porter.asp)